# python (passing parameters to functions)

Tags: python, function

I'm not really new to python but I came across this problem that has just puzzled me.

So I was solving the maze runner problem, using A* and then was finding the hardest possible maze for a given dimension. For this purpose, I created a function called generateHardMaze() that is called from the main function and takes an attribute newMaze.

Now here is where things get weird, **when I change the value of newMaze in the if condition within the while loop the hardMaze value changes without the code entering the second if condition.** I'm not really sure why this happening was hoping someone could help me.

I'm using pycharm as my IDE and python3.6.* if that makes any difference.

I'm sure this isn't how oops works but I'm thinking this is a python thing. Has anyone ever come across anything like this? If yes please sympathize.

Thanks in advance.

```
def solveMazeAManH(newMaze,rows,cols):
    startTime = time.time()

    backTrackPriority = []

    setup_cells(rows, cols)

    # start and end points of the maze
    start = (0, 0)
    end = (rows - 1, cols - 1)

    current = start

    print("The path to be take is: ")

    print(current)

    frinLength = 0

    # traversing the neighbours
    while current != end:

        unvisited.remove(current)

        neighboursDFSandA(newMaze, current, rows, cols)

        heuristic = calManhattanDis(current, end)  # finding the heuristic for every traversal

        try:
            if not currentNeighbours:

                if not backTrackPriority:
                    print("No path available!")
                    return 0
                else:
                    while not currentNeighbours:
                        current = nextPopMan(backTrackPriority, end)
                        backTrackPriority.remove(current)
                        neighboursDFSandA(newMaze, current, rows, cols)

            neighbor = leastPathChildMan(heuristic, current, end)
            backTrackPriority.append(current)
            current = neighbor
            print(current)
            frinLength += 1

        except:
            print("No path Found!")
            return 0

    return frinLength

    endTime = time.time()

    print("The time taken to solve the maze using A* with manhattan distance: ")
    print(startTime - endTime)


def generateHardMaze(newMazes):

    rows = len(newMazes)
    cols = len(newMazes[0])

    hardMaze = newMaze

    print("Solving the original maze!")
    fringLength = solveMazeAManH(newMazes, rows, cols)
    print("Creating new harder Maze:")

    pFlag = True
    pCout = 0

    while pFlag:

        count = 0
        flag = True

        while flag:

            point = choice(setup_cells(rows, cols))

            if (newMazes[point[0]][point[1]] == 1):
                newMazes[point[0]][point[1]] = 0
            else:
                newMazes[point[0]][point[1]] = 1

            if (fringLength < solveMazeAManH(newMazes, rows, cols)):
                print("Harder Maze--------------------")
                hardMaze = newMaze
                fringLength = solveMazeAManH(newMazes, rows, cols)
                count = 0

            else:
                count += 1
                if count >= 10:
                    flag = False

        print("one")
        newMazes = creatMaze(rows)
        pCout += 1
        if pCout >= 100:
            pFlag = False
    print(hardMaze)
```

Comment: Please paste the full code here. There are too many variables you haven't defined here.

Comment: *Not* full code; post the smallest example that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The code is available at: https://github.com/pbharathreddy/MazeRunner